# Rails - Sunspot Solr 404 Error after Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

I just installed Sunspot Solr in my rails app and after starting the server, I'm getting this error..

```
Started GET "/faq/search?search=blueberry" for 143.183.25.73 at 2012-03-22 17:34:27 -0700
Processing by FaqController#search as 
Parameters: {"search"=>"blueberry"}
Keyword Load (0.8ms)  SELECT distinct(content) FROM `keywords` LIMIT 30
SOLR Request (5.2ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x000000033c1808> parameters={data:   fq=type%3AQuestion&q=blueberry&fl=%2A+score&qf=content_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms

RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error: NOT_FOUND

Request Data: "fq=type%3AQuestion&q=blueberry&fl=%2A+score&qf=content_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30"
```

The line of code which causes all this mess is this:

```
# sunspot stuff
@search = Question.search do
  fulltext query
end
@questions = @search.results
```

Has anyone seen this Solr 404 error? I did search through the existing solr issues on the web but didn't find this issue. Thanks.

Comment: forgive me for asking, but have you started solr? `bundle exec sunspot-solr start -p 8983`

Comment: Yes, it's definitely running..I can see the process spinning. I started it with -p 8982 since in my sphinx.yml file I have the development port pointing to 8982.

Comment: is sphinx.yml a typo or are you trying to run sunspot against sphinx? :>

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, meant sunspot.yml. I was using Sphinx and am now using solr. Do you think there could be a conflict as I only removed sphinx by commenting it out in the gemfile? Also, when i run a test search in solr, i see this..                                             bash-4.1$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Question.search { fulltext 'omar' }
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error: NOT_FOUND

Request Data: "fq=type%3AQuestion&q=omar&fl=%2A+score&qf=content_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30"

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is pretty old and you may have solved it already, but I was able to solve this problem by commenting out the path in the sunspot.yml file.

It went from (failing):

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

to (working)

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
    #path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    #path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    #path: /solr/test
```